# Understanding Scope on Scala's For Loops (For Comprehension)

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

In Chapter 3 of [Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch03.html), the author gives two examples of for loops / for comprehensions, but switches between using ()'s and {}'s.  Why is this the case, as these inherently look like they're doing the same thing?  Is there a reason `breed <- dogBreeds` is on the 2nd line in example #2?

```
// #1 ()'s
for (breed <- dogBreeds
  if breed.contains("Terrier");
  if !breed.startsWith("Yorkshire")
) println(breed)

// #2 {}'s
for {
  breed <- dogBreeds
  upcasedBreed = breed.toUpperCase()
} println(upcasedBreed)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you read the green Tip:

> for expressions may be defined with
>   parenthesis or curly braces, but using
>   curly braces means you don’t have to
>   separate your filters with semicolons.
>   Most of the time, you’ll prefer using
>   curly braces when you have more than
>   one filter, assignment, etc.

So for comprehension with `() and {}` are the same the only thing that change is the separator used : for `()` you have to use a `semicolon ";"` as separator and for `{}` you use `new line`.

Comment: Another one of Scala's WTF features.  A great language, but littered with sugar that's not only unnecessary, but arguably harmful.

Comment: Semicolon inference doesn't come for free. The other time it bites is `val a = 1 + 2 + 3 <nl> + 4`. This is parsed as `val a = 1.+(2).+(3); 4.unary_+()`

Comment: Note that the first example doesn't compile.

Comment: @arcticpenguin Scala's semicolon inference makes perfect sense (and you're unlikely to screw it up) if you've programmed in Ruby.

Comment: @Ken I programmed in ruby, and the semicolon inference rules doesn't make too much sense for me.